# converting strings within Entity Framework query

Tags: string, entity-framework, formatting

The following query works perfectly fine and populates its dropdown list. The data in the data base is stored in all uppercase, ie PALM BEACH. I want to convert it to Proper case, which obviously i can do after the fact by iterating through the returned list and reformatting BUT I should be able to do it with in the query itself. The following query works fine.

```
 Dim citylist As List(Of String) = (From c In ctx.ziptaxes
                                                   Where c.StateID = ddlStates.SelectedIndex                                                      
                                                   Order By c.City Ascending
                                                   Select c.City).ToList()
```

But if i try to convert it to some thing like this, it fails

```
 Dim citylist As List(Of String) = (From c In ctx.ziptaxes
                                                   Where c.StateID = ddlStates.SelectedIndex
                                                   Let cityname = StrConv(c.City, VbStrConv.ProperCase)
                                                   Order By cityname Ascending
                                                   Select cityname).ToList()
```

I've tried using culture info  and String.Format(c.City, vbProperCase) too and nothing other than the original query works. Any help appreciated.

**ADDENDUM:**
Well some further research is telling me that .Net objects like string conversion and cultureinfo cannot be used prior to the query being run. If that's the case it explains why it isn't working. The following solves my problem BUT I would still like to know if there is way to do it within the LINQ to EF.

```
 Dim citylist As List(Of String) = (From c In ctx.ziptaxes
                                                   Where c.StateID = ddlStates.SelectedIndex
                                                   Order By c.City Ascending
                                                   Select c.City).ToList()
                If citylist.Count > 0 Then
                    For i As Integer = 0 To citylist.Count - 1
                        citylist(i) = StrConv(citylist(i).ToLower(), vbProperCase)
                    Next
                    With ddlCity
                        .Items.Clear()
                        .DataSource = citylist.Distinct()
                        .DataBind()
                        .Items.Insert(0, "Select a city")
                        .SelectedIndex = 0
                    End With
                End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the conversion in your SELECT. Here's an example (with an over-simplified City name converter):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace LinqQuestion
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class StackOverflowTests
    {
        private IEnumerable<City> _cities;

        [TestFixtureSetUp]
        public void Arrange()
        {
            _cities = new List<City>
            {
                new City { Id = 1, Name = "FLINT", StateId = 1 },
                new City { Id = 2, Name = "SAGINAW", StateId = 1 },
                new City { Id = 3, Name = "DETROIT", StateId = 1 },
                new City { Id = 4, Name = "FLint", StateId = 1 }
            };
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestCountryQuery()
        {
            var data = _cities
                .Where(c => c.StateId == 1)
                .OrderBy(c => c.Name)
                .Select(c => StrConv(c.Name))
                .Distinct().ToList();

            Assert.That(data.Count == 3);
        }

        private static string StrConv(string original)
        {
            var firstLetter = original.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper();
            var theRest = original.Substring(1, original.Length - 1).ToLower();
            return firstLetter + theRest;
        }
    }

    public class City
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int StateId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```